# How to replace the object with the new object using javascript or lodash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

i have the datastructure like below,

```
const data = {
    getSomething: {
        id: '1',
        items: [
            { 
                 id: '1',
                 orders: [
                     {
                         id: '1',
                         name: 'one1',
                     }
                 ],
                 subItems: [
                     { id: '1', name: 'subitem1' },
                     { id: '2', name: 'subitem2' },
                 ],
            },
            { 
                 id: '2',
                 orders: [
                     {
                         id: '2',
                         name: 'two1',
                     }
                 ],
                 subItems: [
                     { id: '2', name: 'subitem1' },
                     { id: '3', name: 'subitem2' },
                 ],
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

now i have another data like below,

```
const item1 = { 
                 id: '2',
                 orders: [
                     {
                         id: '3',
                         name: 'one1',
                     }
                 ],
            }
```

i have to replace the item with id 1 in data with the item1 above. how can i do it using lodash. or any other way that i can do it easily.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Please show any attempt to solve your own problem

Comment: Then you end up with 2 items with id: 2, is that intended?

Comment: no it should be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking something like this ?

```js
const data = {
    getSomething: {
        id: '1',
        items: [
            { 
                 id: '1',
                 orders: [
                     {
                         id: '1',
                         name: 'one1',
                     }
                 ],
                 subItems: [
                     { id: '1', name: 'subitem1' },
                     { id: '2', name: 'subitem2' },
                 ],
            },
            { 
                 id: '2',
                 orders: [
                     {
                         id: '2',
                         name: 'two1',
                     }
                 ],
                 subItems: [
                     { id: '2', name: 'subitem1' },
                     { id: '3', name: 'subitem2' },
                 ],
            }
        ],
    }
}

const item1 = { 
                 id: '2',
                 orders: [
                     {
                         id: '3',
                         name: 'one1.......',
                     }
                 ],
                 subItems: [
                     { id: '2', name: 'subitem1....' },
                     { id: '3', name: 'subitem2....' },
                 ],
            }

let result = data.getSomething.items.map(item=> item.id===item1.id ? ({...item1}): item);

console.log('-----Original----', data.getSomething.items);
console.log('-----Updated-----', result);
```

Comment: thanks . is there a method in lodash to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
  getSomething: {
    id: '1',
    items: [{
        id: '1',
        orders: [{
          id: '1',
          name: 'one1',
        }],
        subItems: [{
            id: '1',
            name: 'subitem1'
          },
          {
            id: '2',
            name: 'subitem2'
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        orders: [{
          id: '2',
          name: 'two1',
        }],
        subItems: [{
            id: '2',
            name: 'subitem1'
          },
          {
            id: '3',
            name: 'subitem2'
          },
        ],
      }
    ],
  }
}

const item1 = {
  id: '2',
  orders: [{
    id: '3',
    name: 'one1',
  }],
}

Object.assign(data.getSomething.items.find(item => item.id === item1.id),item1);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will overwrite item with id 1 in data with the item1:

```
const data = {
    getSomething: {
        id: '1',
        items: [
            { 
                 id: '1',
                 orders: [
                     {
                         id: '1',
                         name: 'one1',
                     }
                 ],
                 subItems: [
                     { id: '1', name: 'subitem1' },
                     { id: '2', name: 'subitem2' },
                 ],
            },
            { 
                 id: '2',
                 orders: [
                     {
                         id: '2',
                         name: 'two1',
                     }
                 ],
                 subItems: [
                     { id: '2', name: 'subitem1' },
                     { id: '3', name: 'subitem2' },
                 ],
            }
        ],
    }
}

const item1 = { 
                 id: '2',
                 orders: [
                     {
                         id: '3',
                         name: 'one1',
                     }
                 ],
            }

const oldItem = data.getSomething.items.find(item => item.id == 1);
Object.assign(oldItem, item1);
console.log(data);
```